# OpenVPN certificate OR plugin-auth-pam authentication

Tags: authentication, openvpn

Configuring OpenVPN server, I can enable either certificate-based authentication or username/password authentication using `openvpn-plugin-auth-pam` plugin, but not both at the same time.

I enable username/password authentication as follows:

```
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so login
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
```

But as soon as I add the following lines, my clients configured for certificate authentication stop working with the following messages in the log:

```
TLS Error: Auth Username/Password was not provided by peer        
TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Is there any way to not require username/password from clients that use certificate authentication?

Comment: To my knowledge, if you configure both (cert and pam), it will request both. A client certificate and the authentication via pam. So openvpn does not provide any logic to react on the fact if a client certificate was presented or not.

Comment: I've just had the same issue. I can't see a way to do this.  The more I looked into it the better option (for me) was to run two instances on the same box. I ended up answering my own question http://serverfault.com/questions/618364/is-dual-alternative-authentication-user-pass-or-client-certificate-possible-wi

Comment: I ended up running two instances as well.

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN does not support multiple concurrent authentication methods. The best solution for this, as mentioned in comments, is to run two instances of OpenVPN. It is more complicated to run it on the same box, but is definitely do-able.

However, there do seem to be some workarounds that may be suitable for your situation.

> if you know which certificates require a password and which don't , then the answer is yes.
>   use an 'auth-user-pass-verify' script on the server side to first verify 
>   the certificate DN (if you set --username-as-common-name as well then 
>   you will know the certificate common name inside the verify script 
>   automatically).
>   if it's a certificate for which you know that a password was entered 
>   then use pam to verify the username/password.
>   if you know the certificate did not include a password then have the 
>   script return '0' to allow access.
>
> Note that there is no way of automaGically determining if the user typed 
>   in a certificate password or not - that's outside the openssl handshake 
>   and thus not known to the OpenVPN server.

Source: https://openvpn.net/archive/openvpn-users/2007-12/msg00179.html

You may also be able to federate your OpenVPN generated keypairs into a local LDAP server, and use the aforementioned script to authentication against LDAP with the provided certificate, or use the provided credentials given that no certificate was presented.